# Twilio allow all reservation updates policy is not working

Tags: javascript, twilio

I am generating a token on the backend

```
allow_reservation_updates = Twilio::JWT::TaskRouterCapability::Policy.new(
    Twilio::JWT::TaskRouterCapability::TaskRouterUtils
        .all_reservations(APP_CONFIG['twilio']['workspace_sid'], worker_sid), 'POST', true
)
capability.add_policy(allow_reservation_updates)

allow_reservation_reads = Twilio::JWT::TaskRouterCapability::Policy.new(
    Twilio::JWT::TaskRouterCapability::TaskRouterUtils
        .all_reservations(APP_CONFIG['twilio']['workspace_sid'], worker_sid), 'GET', true
)
capability.add_policy(allow_reservation_reads)

msg = {:token => capability.to_s }
render :json => msg
```

On the front end, I am successfully creating a worker and listening for the 'reservation.created ' event, then I am trying to accept the call on the web browser.

```
worker = new Twilio.TaskRouter.Worker(data.token)
worker.on 'reservation.created', (reservation) ->
  reservation.accept()
```

So far so good the worker is created and the call back it's been called, but when I call reservation.accept() I am getting an error

```
403 Policies defined such that we cannot access the given resource
```

When I am tracing the token I see that I have access to Reservations subresource of Worker resource,

```
"https://taskrouter.twilio.com/v1/Workspaces/workspace_id/Workers/worker_sid/Reservations/**",
  "method": "POST",
  "query_filter": {},
  "post_filter": {},
  "allow": true
},
```

but the call that Twilio trying to make is upon Reservation subresource of Taks resource

```
method: "POST"
params: {ReservationStatus: "accepted"}
token: "tokenabc"
url: "https://taskrouter.twilio.com/v1/Workspaces/workspace_sid/Tasks/task_sid/Reservations/reservation_sid"
```

How can I assign the policy for tasks subresource Reservation?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I have found it, I had to allow add a policy for all subresources.

```
allow_updates_subresources = Twilio::JWT::TaskRouterCapability::Policy.new(
    Twilio::JWT::TaskRouterCapability::TaskRouterUtils.all_workspaces,
    'POST',
    true
)
capability.add_policy(allow_updates_subresources)
```